# How can I scale meshes so that outside parts don't morph using morph targets?

Tags: three.js, 3d

I am building a room configurator in three.js. I have a mesh that represents a window in a wall of a room, like this:

[image: not scaled mesh]

When I am scaling this mesh normally to make the window wider, I get something like this:

[image: scaled mesh]

Is there a way to make this mesh morph nonuniformly so the frame stays about the same size while scaling? There was a similar problem asked on three.js forum before: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/resize-object-without-distortion/786 . The solution seems to be to use morph targets, but I have no idea how this can be done. Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750987/controlling-the-scaling-of-custom-geometries-in-three-js/54754208#54754208

Comment: @Marquizzo this solution would be ok if you generated a mesh within the app. I have an OBJ model loaded to the scene. It doesn't have to be perfect, I just don't want it to distort that much on the edges.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But maybe you could ask the same question at https://discourse.threejs.org/ there are lots of ThreeJS aficionados over there that would be happy to help you out.